# Loading variables in external folder: only works once

Tags: php, session, variables, include

I'm successfully using the following script to load session variables within other folders on my site:

```
<?php
require('../includes/configure.php');
ini_set('include_path', DIR_FS_CATALOG . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'));
chdir(DIR_FS_CATALOG);
require_once('includes/application_top.php');
?>
```

This script allows me to load my header template right after, which includes the variable output that I want:

```
<?php
include('includes/templates/header.php');
?>
```

So, the thing is this script works flawlessly in three other scenarios (CMS systems)... For this particular one I'm working on, it only works the first time. It does successfully load my header and variables correctly, **however the next time the page load it won't work**.

Can anyone provide an explanation / solution? Thanks!

Comment: Could you give more details as far as 'it wont work' is concerned? What does it do exactly? Does it give you an error in your browser, have you checked your php error log?

Comment: @Patrick Ok so I checked my logs and the only thing I see related to this folder is: [Mon May 30 10:14:30 2011] [error] [client blah.blah.blah.76] File does not exist: /home/dev/public_html/faq/images/feedback.gif, referer: http://www.mysite.com/faq/... Don't know how I'm getting a blank page from this. I know it has something to do with the first snippet of code I posted, because when I view the source it's blank right under the body tag, right where that code is placed.

Comment: are you setting any session variables anywhere which might affect this? The fact that it doesn't work the second time would seem to point to something like that

Comment: Start by eliminating pieces of your code. Take parts out in 'chunks', so as not to break the page, but remove blocks of code. Remove a piece, try it again. If the problem persists, put that code back, and try another. Do this until you can affect a change.

Answer (score 0):

As you answered to a comment that "it won't work" means "I get a blank page", the first thing you should do is **enable PHP's error reporting**. Put at the beginning of your script:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); // shows in the web page instead of just logs
```

Then your page probably won't stay blank and you'll have useful error messages.

Second, you should replace your `include` by a `require`. This way, if PHP cannot find the file, you'll get a fatal error. Depending on the content, a `require_once` could be even better suited.

Then, you should be cautious with relative paths in includes. They are not immediately relative to the script where the include is. PHP first tries to use the include path and the path of the calling script (the file that was launched first for this HTTP query). It is recommended to use a full path :

```
require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/includes/configure.php';
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/includes/configure.php'; // PHP5.3 only
```

One last thing: don't use the expression *session variables* when you're dealing with application *constants*. "Session" has a special meaning in PHP, and in web development in general.